# How to set python IDLE to use pythonpath variable in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: python, pythonpath, python-idle

I have set a pythonpath variable in my ~/.bashrc and it works fine when using python interpreter from the command line and bpython, but IDLE is not recognizing it.

How can I configure it to load the pythonpath variable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: perhaps a candidate for askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

- You can upgrade Ubuntu, because it works fine on my 10.10 machine with the idle-python2.7 package and PYTHONPATH set in my ~/.profile (which shouldn't matter because bash normally loads both)
- Or you can change sys.path in /usr/bin/idle* as per [Setting PYTHONPATH for idle?](http://www.uluga.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=253555)